# No PDF output from ReportBuilder

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I have a ReportBuilder report that preview's as expected.
I'm trying to save it to pdf with the following code taken from the documentation:

```
ppReport1.ShowPrintDialog := false;
ppReport1.DeviceType := dtPDF;
ppReport1.TextFileName := 'C:\temp\report.pdf';
ppReport1.Print;
```

I get a glimpse of an dialog on the screen, stating that it outputs a couple of pages to the given file, but the file is no where to be found on disk.

What have I missed?

Comment: Your best bet is to email their support or post in their forums. Their support has always been top notch in the past for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)  showed me that the file was written, but then deleted.
After a lot of source code browsing, I found the cause of this.

There is a property under `EmailSettings` called `DeleteFile`. For some reason, it also effects printing to file.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking this property:

```
ppReport1.AllowPrintToFile := True;
```

It works fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange. I just use by this way:

```
  ppReport1.AllowPrintToFile := True;
  ppReport1.ShowPrintDialog  := False;
  ppReport1.DeviceType       := 'PDF';
  ppReport1.TextFileName     := 'C:\temp\report.pdf';
  ppReport1.Print;
```

(I'm using it on ReportBuilder v14.07)

Comment: We're still at version 12.4 with Delphi XE.